# rear derailer broken

Tags: derailleur, shifter

[image]

[image]

what model and number of derailer should I reorder for a replacement?

Thanks, Dave

Comment: That picture is flipped both upside down and horizontally.  How/why did you do that?!

Comment: The looks like a Onamihs Yenruot.

Comment: It's a Shimano Tourney, only from an alternate universe.  With, I'm guessing, 7i speeds.

Comment: What shifters have you go at the other end. The wheel thing the cable goes into looks like some kind of  problem solver (and by the way the cable enters the derailleur, I suspect its causing more problems than it solves)

Comment: The wheel probably is an artifact of an earlier design.  Likely with a new derailer a longer cable housing will be needed, to allow it to loop around back vs using the pulley.

Comment: Really upside down and mirror.  That takes effort.

Comment: It's like when I bought a Rolex in Shanghai and then only noticed later that it's a Roley.

Comment: I have seen some of these old Tourneys that are normal low. With the cable disconnected it will shift onto the largest gear.

Comment: What's wrong with it that you need a replacement ?

Answer (score 1):

Its a Shimano Tourney mech and the cage seems to be a mid-length one.

The mount point seems to NOT have a separate hanger, so you do need something with a "Direct Mount" which is the bolt at the top, like this:

[image: http://i.ebayimg.com/thumbs/images/g/8DEAAOSwoudW77eM/s-l200.jpg] <-- Yes

and NOT a frame mount that goes under the axle nut like this one:

[image: http://i.ebayimg.com/thumbs/images/g/ghQAAOSw91NTs3k8/s-l200.jpg] <-- Nope

Start here http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw=shimano+tourney+rear+megarange+direct

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I've ordered the "YES" one. Will see if it works and I did okay. Thanks again.. Dave